# Unable to import a vuejs library

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component, node-modules

I am making a tiny vuejs library just to learn how to make one. Let's call it swing and this is how the file is structured.

[image]

The `conf/`, `dist/`, `test/` files are empty

I have pushed this library to github and published it to npm.
I installed it into my app using

```
npm install --save vuejs-swing
```

I can see it's installed in `package.json` and `node_modules` folder, but when I do:

```
import swing from 'vuejs-swing'
```

I get this error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                11:42:41 AM

This dependency was not found:

* vuejs-swing in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0&bustCache!./src/c
omponents/HelloWorld.vue

To install it, you can run: npm install --save vuejs-swing
```

It is obviously intalled so it must be a configuration issue

This is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      // use babel-loader for js files
      { test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
      // use vue-loader for .vue files
      { test: /\.vue$/, use: 'vue-loader' }
    ]
  },
  // default for pretty much every project
  context: __dirname,
  // specify your entry/main file
  entry: {
    app: './src/swing.js',
    
  },
  output: {
    // specify your output directory...
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'output'),
    // and filename
    filename: 'index.min.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    // this is optional, but it lets you import .vue files without the .vue extension.
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue']
  }
}



if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

#### EDIT:

I will award the bounty to whomever who can provide the tools, configs necessary to publish a package in npm and be able to impor/use it.

Comment: Can you show us the code for swing.vue?  I'm wondering if you aren't exporting your component correctly

Comment: @TimHutchison I am just exporting a simple stuff like `export.module = 'swing'`

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

- Make sure your `output` folder is not ignored by git (shouldn't be in the `.gitignore` file)
- Build your package for production (run Webpack)
- In your `package.json` point the `main` file to `./output/index.min.js` and **NOT** to `./src/swing.js`

```js
{
  "name": "vuejs-swing",
  "version": "0.1.2",
  "main": "./output/index.min.js",
  // ...
}
```

Don't except your package's users to build the sources (run Webpack) for you, you need to point them to a pre-packaged javascript file.

As a side note, the package `vuejs-swing` is not *publicly* published on npm as for now. I don't know if you changed the package name or working on a private repository.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem. I only corrected the package.json as all the other were ok. (output is not gitignored and my library is in another name not swing) so, only thing to add was the `"main": "./output/index.min.js",` the output folder and it's js file are generated. I commited the changes  bumped up the versions and republished it to npm. Even though the error is gone  after `import swing from 'vuejs-swing'` but `swing` isn't defined. I added it to `components: {swing}` but nothing.

Comment: Would be nice to have a link to GitHub